# PHP/MySQL or Node.JS/MongoDB?

Tags: database, web, server-side, backend

For the past months I've been trying to learn as much HTML/CSS/JS as I could. I know it's fairly early but I'm thinking of jumping to back-end language + a database query language since I will have the whole summer to my self, thus I will be able to practice them all at once with multiple projects. I have programming experience (C#/Java/Python) so learning new languages isn't really hard now. I was wondering, which is better PHP/MySQL or Node.JS/MongoDB ? I see a lot of hate for PHP and a lot of hype for Node.JS lately, and even though I've tried out Node.JS for some bots, I somehow subconciously prefer PHP/MySQL as I find it more "formal" for some reason. What should I pick? I don't know how much I like JavaScript but I see PHP getting some hate for it's syntax too (mysqli or something). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL with both PHP and Node.js as a relational database plus you wan use Mongo with PHP or Node as a JSON document store.  And you can use MySQL with the new X DevAPI as a document store (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/).

It depends more on where you want to go more than a choice of language.

Comment: Would there be any problem if I were to jump at HTML/CSS/JS/PHP/MySQL at the same time ?

Answer (score -2):

you should use nodejs with mongodb if you want performance. use Myql if you do not want relational db.

Comment: There is no database called Myql. If you mean MySQL, then it is a relational database.

Comment: Dear Jule, its MySQL. Please don't give negative score for my spell error and re consider for positive. You know it very well it was MySql not Myql. Thanks

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that you're suggesting to use MySQL if he doesn't want a relational DB although MySQL **is** a relational DB. That is not a good piece of advice.